# Table View similar the Add Contact within a Modal View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How would I create a `UITableView` similar to the Add Contact or Add Event ones within a Modal View?

I know how to create my Modal View and put a `UITableView` in it, but how would I create the grouped editable cells, the add photo button etc. within a `UITableView`?

I'm assuming what is in the Add Contact Modal View is indeed a `UITableView`, if not, how would I recreate this anyway with my custom fields for input?

Thanks.

Comment: I also faced some difficulty in this, its better to go with UI component like UITextField,UiimageView,Ui Label..place these according to ur need.This will be too easy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this with help from saadnib. Thanks!

I created custom UITableViewCells in the same xib as the TableView and assigned them as IBOutlets in the classes @interface.

Then in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: I just checked the row and returned the correct cell in the order I wanted them in since what I was trying to do just required static table cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return cell0;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        return cell1;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        return cell2;
    }
    return cell0;
}
```

I had tried to do this countless times before without it working, this was because the cells I was trying to return were null because the class didn't know where they were because they hadn't been loaded into memory from the nib file. Thus, adding this line of code in viewDidLoad: was necessary.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNibFile" owner:self options:nil];
```

Everything seems to work fine now, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In Add Contact there are custom cell in table view with an background image and for editable mode there are textfields. So what i am trying to say that you can create custom cells in table with textfields and buttons.

Comment: Yeah I know this but whenever I've done that in the past, it's been many iterations of one custom cell. In the Add Contact or Add Event tables, the cells are very different. How would I implement this programmatically?

Comment: You can check in cellForRowAtIndexPath for indexPath.row and can make different cell according it.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about this, I'll give it a go. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so I did what you tried. I realised that what I'm trying to create has only static content. So I should be able to just check the indexPath.row and return a cell for that row. Easy. Except on runtime the app is having trouble finding the cell to return. I've declared the cell (UITableViewCell) in the @interface, written a @property for it and @synthesised it. But when I try and return it in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, the console gives this error: UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: which suggests it just can't find the cell to return. Any ideas?

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath: have you this statement return cell;

Comment: Yeah, I posted the code I used as an answer. I had done that before but cellForRowAtIndexPath: couldn't find the cell I wanted to return. I realised it was because the nib data wasn't loaded into memory, which was fixed by the line of code included in my answer. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think a table view is not the best way to go about this.  Although it looks like a grouped table view, the add to contacts is highly customised.

One of the main advantages of a table view is having a dynamic size. For the contacts view it is mostly fixed.

Create a view controller and add images, text views and labels is my advice.

Comment: I would do that but I had planned for some of my custom cells to have disclosure indicators which would push a view onto the nav stack when pressed. I suppose I could do this with a normal button but it would look or feel as natural as with a disclosure cell.